# Ordering preserved by an inverse frame homomorphism

Tags: gn.general-topology, lattices, order-theory, lattice-theory, universal-algebra

Recall that a frame homomorphism  $h:L\to M$ is called ($L$ and $M$ are frames):

1. Dense if, for any $x ∈ L$, $h(x) = 0$ implies $x = 0$.
2. Codense if, for any $x ∈ L$, $h(x) = 1$ implies $x = 1$.
3. Coherent  if it maps compact elements to compact elements.

How can we prove the following:

> Let $h: L \to M$ be a surjective, dense , codense and coherent frame homomorphism, and $a, b\in L$. Then $a\leq b$ (in $L$) if and only if $h(a)\leq h(b)$( in $M$).

(Clearly, if $a\leq b$, then $h(a)\leq h(b)$.)

(Recall that a  frame is a complete lattice $L$ satisfying the distributivity law
$(\vee A) ∧ b = \vee\{a ∧ b | a \in A\}$
for any subset  $A$ of $L$ and any $b \in L$ and a frame homomorphism is a homomorphism of posets that preserves finite meets and arbitrary joins.)

Comment: A definition, or link to definition of frames, would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think the statement is not true, and here is a proposed counterexample.

Let $L=[0,1]$ be the unit interval of the real line, ordered as usual, considered as a frame. The only compact element of $L$ is $0$.

Let $h\colon L\to L$ be the continuous, nondecreasing, piecewise linear function that maps $[0,1/3]$ in a linear and increasing way onto $[0,1/2]$, is constant on $[1/3,2/3]$ with value $1/2$, and which maps $[2/3,1]$ in a linear increasing way onto $[1/2,1]$. For this example we have that $h$ is dense, codense, and coherent, but $h(2/3)\leq h(1/3)$, while $2/3\not\leq 1/3$.

Comment: For a finite version one might restrict your $h$ to $h:\{0,1/3,2/3,1\}\to\{0,1/2,1\}$